# Group inside group

Tags: regex

```
/(test|test1|is(cold|warm|large|small))/
```

`iscold / iswarm / islarge / issmall` are two different groups since "is" is from group1 and everything behind it is from group 2.
How can I make it into one group so `iscold|iswarm|islarge|issmall` should be one group, without having to type "is" everytime infront of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, they are already in the same group (number 1). You just match the `cold`/`warm`... part in a second group *too*, which apparently you don't care about.

If you want to avoid this useless capture, you can use a non capturing group `(?:...)`;

```
/(test|test1|is(?:cold|warm|large|small))/
```

Answer (score 4):

Use non capturing groups for the sub parts.

```
/(test|test1|is(?:cold|warm|large|small))/
```